# Turn dataframe column into list of integers / floats (not string). tolist() not working

Tags: list, dataframe, integer

So I have dataframe with a column names "expense" that has floating numbers in them like this-

```html
expense

20.00

15.00

3.00

6.00

3.00

2.5
```

I wanted to turn that into a list. I used temp['expense'].tolist() and I got this-

```html
['$20.00', '$15.00', '$3.00', '$6.00', '$3.00', '$2.50']
```

which is a list of strings. I want the floating numbers to stay float so I can do math on them later. What can I do to achieve that?

Kind of new to it. So thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
temp['expense'].str[1:].astype(float).tolist()
```

If every entry in `temp['expense']` has a dollar sign, then it should work.